# jqGrid Edit Grid fails when column value has space

Tags: jqgrid, edit

I am new to jqGrid. I am working on creating a grid with edit functionality to each row. I was able to successfully create the grid and edit the rows. But i found that when there i space in my name column(editable column) in the grid. the edit doesn't work. The row remains disabled if i click on pencil icon.

For Example: the edit works if name is like 'test' but fails when name is 'test run'.

```js
$(this.tableElement).jqGrid('GridUnload');
$(this.tableElement).jqGrid({
    url: url1,
    editurl: urledit,
    mtype: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    postData: {
        id: ID
    },
    colNames: [
        '&nbsp;Name',
        '&nbsp;ID',
        'QuoID',
        ''
    ],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Name', id: 'Name', width: 50, sorttype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'ID', id: 'ID', hidden: true, editable: true },
        { name: 'QuoID', id: 'QuoID', hidden: true, editable: true },
        {
            name: 'Actions', index: 'Actions', width: 30, height: 120, formatter: 'actions',
            formatoptions: {
                keys: true,
                onEdit: function (rowid)
                { alert(rowid); }
            }
        },
    ],        

    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 100],
    sortname: 'PackageID',
    sortorder: "desc",
    firstsortorder: 'desc',
    loadonce: !GetFeatureToggle("MultiplePackages"),
    sortable: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Packages",
    width: 450,
    height: 200,
    hidegrid: false,

    loadComplete: function (data) {
        if (_this.firstLoad == true) {
            setTimeout(function () { $(_this.elements.list).jqGrid('setGridParam', { page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid"); }, 1);
            _this.firstLoad = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you use the column with `name: "test run"` or you just has `"test run"` text in some row of the `Name` column? Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you include the test data (returned from `url1`), which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: hi oleg, the column has a row with value as 'test run'. i guess am using jqgrid version 4.3. The test data returned by url1 will be the tables values. for ex: id name quoid - 1 test run 12345, 2 pack2 23445. please let me know any specific information is needed

Comment: hi oleg,i could see the below error if i try to run in IE. function onclick(event){jquery.fn.fmatter.rowactions('Infinity} . Function terminated with inncorect string. Ideally only the first part of the full value has been considered.

Comment: for the value without space the event is triggered like  function onclick(event)
{
jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions('hello','NewProfileExistingGrid_Table_Package','edit',3);
}

Comment: The `formater: "action"` placed rowid and grid id as parameters of `jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions` method. The value inside of the column `Name` should be not important. The version of jqGrid which you use is really important. The version 4.3 is really retro version. It's 5 years old, which is about 50 years for web development. Every version introduces some new features, which has bugs, which will be fixed later. It has no sense to use jqGrid 4.3 now.

Comment: First of I recommend you to load free jqGrid 4.13.5 directly from CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). You need modify only 3 lines of your HTML code and you will see whether the problem is the bug in retro version of jqGrid, which you used or you have probably some other problem.

Comment: Hi oleg,did you find any issues in the way results are retrieved and displayed in grid. I fetch data from db and return as "return (new LargeJsonResult(new GenericAjaxFunctionResult<object>(new { rows = retrievedQuotes.ToArray(), total = totalPages, records = totalRecords, page = page })));" The issue looks like the space is picked up worngly.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. The code fragment is unclear (language C#/Java, Database engine and so on). Do you use `loadonce: true` or not? The server code should depends on that. How many total rows are in the dataset (in `retrievedQuotes`): 100, 1000, 10000, ...? You original question was about **spaces in id**. It's restriction of HTML5 and has no direct relation to the server code of JSON data. The value of `name` property of `colModel` will be used to build ids of HTML5 element, thus one can't use spaces in the names. One can still use spaces **in data** (inside of cells).

Comment: Do you tried whether you have any problems with spaces in data if you replace the URLs of jqGrid files to URLs or free jqGrid 4.13.5, which I posted you before? Editing of 3 lines of HTML code take one minute only.